# stacked bar chart in r for multiple data frames

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Sorry to bother you guys once again, but I'm struggling with a simple task and after looking for a solution and browsed internet, I cannot sort it out.
here's the deal. I have three arrays

```
c1 <- data.frame(cf=rep(100,10),m=seq(1,10,1))
c1$cf[10] <- 500

c2 <- data.frame(cf=rep(50,10),m=seq(1,20,2))
c2$cf[10] <- 650

c3 <- data.frame(cf=rep(150,5),m=seq(1,20,4))
c3$cf[5] <- 450
```

and I'd like to create a stacked bar chart with a sequence from 1 to 20 along x (all the possible entries of the three second columns) and the (possible) sum of the three first columns along y.

I tried to merge the three data frames

```
m <- merge(c1,c2,by="m",all=TRUE)
m <- merge(m,c3,by="m",all=TRUE)
```

I melted it

```
m1 <- melt(m,id="m")
m1 <- na.exclude(m1)
```

and tried to use ggplot as

```
ggplot(data=m1,aes(x=m,y=value,fill=row))
```

but I don't get anything and still don't know how to show the bar chart in a right way and if this is the right way to do what I want to get.

In case, thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You are going to need to include what you tried and didn't work, in order for anyone to explain *why* it didn't work.  Also, the above is not valid R code - a <- data.frame(...) + c <- d.  By '+' do you mean ';'?  Since you already browsed internet, you might like to indicate what solutions you tried, and what resources you found, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's look at your data:

```
head(m1)
#   m variable value
# 1 1     cf.x   100
# 2 2     cf.x   100
# 3 3     cf.x   100
# 4 4     cf.x   100
# 5 5     cf.x   100
# 6 6     cf.x   100
```

Looks fine. Now let's look are your plotting command:

```
ggplot(data=m1,aes(x=m,y=value,fill=row))
```

Two issues: first, referencing your data above there is no column called "row". I assume you want the fill color based on the column called "variable":

```
ggplot(data = m1, aes(x = m, y = value, fill = variable))
# Error: No layers in plot
```

Second, what type of plot? Bar plot? Scatterplot? Boxplot? you need to tell `ggplot` what to plot. This is what what the error message is telling you - you've provided data but no indication of *what* to plot. This is covered in any introduction to `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(data = m1, aes(x = m, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar()
```

But now we get another error:

> Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
>     With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
>     This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
>     If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
>     If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
>     See ?geom_bar for examples. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.2)

It's a helpful error, the best kind! *If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".*

```
ggplot(data = m1, aes(x = m, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

And it works.

Comment: I really thank you!!! the best help I could receive! just a further question. To get this result, starting from my three data frames, was there a better procedure? or I really had to merge before, melt and exclude the NA values? thanks a lot again

Comment: This is definitely good. Working with 1 data frame is much easier than working with 3, and long-format data is always preferred by ggplot2. You may enjoy reading [the Tidy Data paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinn6uO-abJAhWUU4gKHaDuBCMQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvita.had.co.nz%2Fpapers%2Ftidy-data.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFUAQr-w_87XpPhfEDoDYQw5-G5zg&sig2=WuLdOUDHPBJAmGLo-94PiA). It's a pretty quick read and can be very helpful in learning how to think about problems like this.